# Laravel API Register User - Check Duplicate Email

Tags: laravel

I am using a Laravel 5.5 API route in `routes/api.php` to register new users like this.

```
Route::post('users/', function(Request $request) {

    $user = new User;

    if (Input::get('name')) {
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
    }

    if (Input::get('email')) {
        $user->name = $request->input('email');
    }

    if (Input::get('password')) {
        $user->name = $request->input('password');
    }
    
    $user->save();

)};
```

But if I have an email address already in the database that matches then I get an SQL error because the field is set to unique.

How can I check the email isn't a duplicate before I get to attempting to post it to the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couple ways to do this. One, use FormRequests and define the rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users'
    ];
}
```

Two, use the ValidatesRequests trait on your controller and call `validate` within the method:

```
$this->validate($request, [...rules...])
```

If the validation fails it will redirect the user back with errors, or if ajax, send a json response with the error bag.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: When I try and use validate I get the error message '"Attribute [validate] does not exist'

Comment: Are you using it at the top of the register method in your controller? `public function register ($request) { $this->validate($request, [rules array]); ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Please try following.

```
Route::post('users/', function(Request $request) {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'unique:user_table|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validatedData->fails()) {
        return redirect('your_defined_route')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    $user = new User;

    if (Input::get('name')) {
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
    }

    if (Input::get('email')) {
        $user->name = $request->input('email');
    }

    if (Input::get('password')) {
        $user->name = $request->input('password');
    }

    $user->save();
)};
```